# Override web Firebase cloud messaging background notification with custom behavior

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have a Firebase web project with a service worker that handles background notifications. By default, Firebase displays any background notifications sent to the user. I want to prevent this from happening, so I can show a different message based off the received message. I tried doing this:

```
import { FirebaseOptions, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging, onBackgroundMessage } from 'firebase/messaging/sw';

const firebaseOptions: FirebaseOptions = {
    // Firebase config
};

initializeApp(firebaseOptions);

const messaging = getMessaging();

onBackgroundMessage(messaging, () => {
    self.registration.showNotification('Overriden message');
});
```

Right now, the device shows both the message received from the server, and the overridden message. I would like it to only show the overridden message so I can customize the behavior. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently "notification" fields in your HTTP send request take precedence over any values specified in the service worker ([source](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/71#issuecomment-258872970))

Try encapsulating the notification field in your request with a data field so that

```
"notification": {
  "title": "hello",
  "body": "world"
}
```

Becomes:

```
"data": {
  "notification": {
    "title": "hello",
    "body": "world"
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, there are some other workarounds you can try [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/71).